# How to format an integer field as Date/Time using Views module

Tags: 7, views

I created a custom Entity with one of the properties named 'created' and set with the Drupal `REQUEST_TIME` in seconds. I want to display this property using the Views module as a formatted Date/Time field. The Date/Time format option is not offered on the Views field settings dialogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `hook_entity_property_info_alter()` to describe your custom entity type's properties to the Entity API module, which will then automatically create Views integration based on the types of fields in your database table.

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info_alter/7

An example of this can be found in the Log module, which has three timestamps (timestamp, created, and changed). It gives each of these a "type" of "date" in the entity property info, which automatically makes them visible to Views as date fields. http://cgit.drupalcode.org/log/tree/log.module#n242

Comment: Why `hook_entity_property_info_alter()` instead of `hook_entity_property_info()`? I just implemented `hook_entity_property_info()` for the 'created' property but the Views configuration page reports the error message `Broken/missing handler`. I don't know how I'm supposed to define this handler.

Comment: Wow `hook_entity_property_info_alter` worked. I'd think that `hook_entity_property_info` would work as well but apparently it didn't. Or maybe I did not implement it correctly?